# NHibernate and generic list in abstract base class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, class, abstract, radix

This is kind of a complicated question and I've tried so many angle I can't remember what I have and haven't tried yet. But basically, my project consist of some base classes for a football league. I have the following classes:

League - abstract base class for a league in my library
Team - abstract base class for a team in my library

FootballLeague - derived from League (could be any other type of league though e.g. BaseballLeague, SoccerLeague, etc.)
FootballTeam - derived from Team (same as above)

Basically what I'd like to do is have a list of teams in the League class so I can have more general methods in that class that can operate on just Team objects. And then in my FootballLeague be able to reference that same list except get back the FootballTeam objects (which the list really contains).

Here is my implementation so far at a very basic level:

```
public abstract class League
{
   protected IList mTeams;
}

public abstract class Team
{
   public virtual League League
   {
       get;
       protected set;
   }
}

public class FootballLeague : League
{
        public virtual IList<FootballTeam> Teams
        {
            get { return this.mTeams.Cast<FootballTeam>().ToList(); }
            protected set { this.mTeams = value.ToList(); }
        }

        public FootballLeague() : base()
        {
            this.mTeams = new List<FootballTeam>();
            this.mConferences = new List<FootballConference>();
        }
}
```

This works pretty much exactly how I want except for an NHibernate problem.

1) When I load a FootballLeague object, it loads all the FootballTeam objects as well. If I remove the mTeams declaration in the base class and just use an auto get/set for the IList in the FootballLeague object lazy loading works and my teams don't load until actually access the collection. So basically having that member variable that the list accesses in the base class, causes NHiberate to bypass lazy loading.

Is this implementation the way you would handle this type of library. Whereas you have abstract base classes that should have functionality on lists, but the derived classes should also be able to access more specialized versions of the list as well? If not, how should I implement that so it works with NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class League<T> where T : Team
{
    protected IList<T> mTeams;

    public League()
    {
        mTeams = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class FootballLeague : League
{
}
```

and map mTeams as IList and hasmanyToAny to avoid casting errors

Does this work for you?